# Speed up Maxent prediction in R

Tags: raster, r

I am using Maxent in R for performing species distribution modeling. My problem is that raster::predict() is very slow because of the resolution and extent of my environmental data. Is there a way to parallel process the prediction step to speed this up? At the current time it is running for days and this creates problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split your raster brick/stack along the y-axis and pass the subsets to different CPUs using foreach:

```r
#load raster brick
filename = "predictors"
predictors = raster::brick(filename)

#register parallel computing backend
ncores=4
cl = parallel::makeCluster(ncores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl,cores)

#compute indices for data splitting
rows = 1:nrow(predictors)
split = sort(rows%%ncores)+1

outname = "prediction"

#perform the prediction on subsets of the predictor dataset
prediction = foreach(i=unique(split), .combine=c)%dopar%{
  rows_sub = rows[split==i]
  sub = raster::crop(predictors,raster::extent(predictors, min(rows_sub), max(rows_sub), 1, ncol(predictors)))
  raster::predict(sub, model, filename=paste(outname, i, sep="_"))
}
```

This will write different files with a suffix "_1" to "_{ncores}" which can then easily mosaicked back together along the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. However, it does eat up a lot of hard drive space and that is causing me some problems. I am going to ask a new question related to the temporary directory for raster().

Answer (score 2):

using clusterR from the raster package:

```
beginCluster()
preds_rf<- clusterR(rast, raster::predict, args = list(model = model))
endCluster()
```